# How do I call a mailApp function within an onEdit function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an onEdit function where if executed should send an email. However, some research has turned up that the mailApp functions don't work with onEdit. I'm currently toying around with workarounds but wondering if others have solutions they've come up with.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  //if editing specific sheet
  if (sheetName == "draft_test" ) {
    //if editing 6th column
    var r = e.source.getActiveRange();
    if (r.getColumn() == 6 ) {
      var player = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
      // Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons.
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      var response = ui.alert('Do you want to draft '+player+'?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      // Process the user's response.
      if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
        //***********FOR SOME REASON EXECUTING THIS FUNCTION ISNT WORKING******************
        emailLeague();
        //sortAutoRoster();
      } else {
      }
    }
  }
}

function emailLeague() {
  var draftSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("draft_test");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("test_email");
  var emailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Manager Info");

  //actual email address omitted
  var recipient = 'emailaddress@gmail.com';
  //get array of all picks on "draft test" tab, and find latest one
  var picks = draftSheet.getRange(3,6,146,1).getValues();

    for (var i=0; i<picks.length; i++){
    if (picks[i] == ""){
      var latestPick = i;
      break;
    }
   }  
  var subject = sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).getValue();
  var body = sheet.getRange(i+1, 1).getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: It's tough for me to tell without access to the spreadsheet. I'd try adding some kind of debug statement right after each `if` condition like `if (sheetName == "draft_test" ) { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue('Editing draft test - confirmed');`. When you find one that doesn't successfully change the cell value, you'll know which part of the code is breaking...

Comment: That helped debug the issue. It is stalling out once it hits the MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body); step. So the issue isn't about calling a function within a function. It's about why the email won't send.

Comment: @KevinHall Ran fine for me. In fact the onEdit function is a red herring. Just run the `emailLeague`. Two things: 1) Suggest you insert this -`Logger.log("Mail details: recipient:"+recipient+", subject:"+subject+", message: "+body);`  immediately before `sendEmail` and make sure that the mail fields are properly populated.   2) For reasons I cannot explain, the mail was being received by my email system (GMail) without _any_ tags (most odd). So it took an extra bit of hunting to find the email sent by the script.